# Create/Append table with sum of values grouped in different categories

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, append

I have an expense table like:

```
WorkWeek  Catg  Item    Cost
WorkWeek1 Cat1  Item1   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat1  Item2   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat1  Item3   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat1  Item4   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat2  Item1   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat2  Item5   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat2  Item6   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat3  Item1   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat3  Item5   Price
.
.
WorkWeekA CatB  ItemC   Price
```

This is how I am doing it right now:

```
select top(1)
     (select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg like 'Cat1') as Cat1TotalCost
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg like 'Cat2') as Cat2TotalCost
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg like 'Cat3') as Cat3TotalCost
    .
    .
    .
    .
from DataTable where WorkWeek like 'WorkWeek1'
```

And If I don't use the `top 1` then I get the same sums repeated over like thousands of rows. Also, my way of doing it only accounts for 1 workweek. :(

I want to create a Table with each workweeks total expense depending in each category something like :

```
WorkWeek1   Cat1TotalCost   Cat2TotalCost   Cat3TotalCost
WorkWeek2   Cat1TotalCost   Cat2TotalCost   Cat3TotalCost
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you please edit your post and add your question at the bottom? I can figure it out, but it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: Will you have an undefined number of categories?

Comment: Yes I will. There are about 2500 catgs, and they might add up more.
And to add on to that, the Catgs column currently has catg_num on it, and there is another table with the corresponding catg_names. I actually wanted to use some join to fetch back the catg_names as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    workweek
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg = 'Cat1') as Cat1TotalCost
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg = 'Cat2') as Cat2TotalCost
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg = 'Cat3') as Cat3TotalCost
    .
    .
    .
    .
from DataTable
group by Workweek
```

Now, you are grouping by the workweek field.  Also, I changed the `like` to `=` to make it slightly faster.

Comment: No problem.  If the number of categories is likely to change without notice, you should explore pivot queries. Otherwise, this is just fine.

Comment: Hey.
The query described above is summing up all the `cost` columns where catg=cat1
So, I am getting, the same sum for all workweeks. Can I somehow sum it only corresponding to the workweek it is in?

Comment: This should give you 1 row per workweek, with the sums of cat1, cat2, cat3, etc. If you want to limit it to just 1 workweek, then add a where clause at the end, e.g. `where WorkWeek like 'WorkWeek1'`.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks but I will have to manually put in a where clause for every workweek that I might have. So I did: select workweek,
       sum(case when Catg = 'Cat1' then cost end) as Cat1TotalCost,
      .....
from DataTable group by Workweek

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have many categories, are you looking for a grouping ?

```
select worksheet, category, sum(cost) from DataTablegroup by worksheet, category order by worksheet
```

Comment: what I am doing is coming up with a new table that has the sum prices of each category under its own column.