# Group and sum row data into columns in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, append, pivot

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395776/create-append-table-with-sum-of-values-grouped-in-different-categories)

I didn't know If I should open a new question or just un-mark the last one!
So, What I want to do is:

```
WorkWeek  Catg  Item    Cost
WorkWeek1 Cat1  Item1   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat1  Item2   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat2  Item3   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat3  Item4   Price
WorkWeek1 Cat3  Item1   Price
WorkWeek2 Cat1  Item1   Price
WorkWeek2 Cat2  Item2   Price
WorkWeek3 Cat1  Item1   Price
WorkWeek4 Cat1  Item2   Price
.
.
WorkWeekA CatB  ItemC   Price
```

I want to create a new table listing each workweek and then the total of each catg's price in that work week. This is how I am doing it right now, but the query just adds up everything for each ww giving me the same sum for all workweeks:

```
select
    workweek
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg = 'Cat1') as Cat1TotalCost
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg = 'Cat2') as Cat2TotalCost
    ,(select sum(cost) from DataTable where Catg = 'Cat3') as Cat3TotalCost
    .
    .
    .
    .
from DataTable
group by Workweek
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do the pivot like this:

```
select workweek,
       sum(case when Catg = 'Cat1' then cost end) as Cat1TotalCost,
       sum(case when Catg = 'Cat2' then cost end) as Cat2TotalCost,
       sum(case when Catg = 'Cat3' then cost end) as Cat3TotalCost
from DataTable
group by Workweek
```

You should not be doing a separate subquery for each value.

The `pivot` statement is also a very reasonable alternative.  I tend to stick with the explicit version (above), because it gives me more flexibilty in adding columns.

Comment: am trying to implement this soln. I googled around and now know that this is called a cross-tab query approach. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying this in Access but getting stupid syntax error. Looked around but can't find why won't access run this sql code:  select 
  ww
 ,sum(case when f.gl_num='532100'   then valuecocur end) as Chem from fadsfd f

Comment: @camelbrush . . . In access you have to use `iif` instead of `case`.

Comment: what I did is used SSMA to get the db into ms sql then used your example to write my query. It works good for me.
:)
Thanks a lot. Is there any reason, I should get into learning about the PIVOT option in sql?

Comment: @camelbrush . . . If you regularly use a database that supports `pivot` (such SQL Server), then it is a very handy tool.  I often switch databases, so I tend toward more inter-database compatible syntax.

Comment: okay. thanks. should start learning it then. have any good tutorial in mind withe simple examples?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you should probably add an ISNULL check for each sum so that it wouldn't be null (a sum of numbers is always 0 or more).

Comment: @UriAbramson . . . The original query would return `NULL` if there were no matches.  This version can easily be changed to add `else 0` to each of the conditions.  An additional function call is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`PIVOT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator to do so instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT workweek, catg, cost
  FROM datatable
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(cost)
  FOR catg IN (Cat1, Cat2, Cat3)
) AS p;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83383/5)

---

If you don't want to list the `catg` values manually, and you want to do this dynamically for all the values of the `catg` in the table, you can do this dynamically using dynamic SQL. Something like:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(catg)
                      FROM datatable                      
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 
    'SELECT 
      *
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT workweek, catg, cost
      FROM datatable
    ) AS t
    PIVOT
    (
      SUM(cost)
      FOR catg IN ( ' + @cols + ')
    ) AS p';



EXECUTE( @query);
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83383/8)

Comment: Can this be run in access?